# como preguntar en sql server tablas y columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

alguien me puede ayudar necesito saber como consultar la cantidad de películas por categoría en SQL server  intente con esto

```
SELECT count (nombre) 
FROM Categoria 
where nombre='Terror'
```

y me arroja un 1 pero sin nombre ni nada mi idea que me diga por ejemplo 1 de terror o una pelicula de terror , las tablas son categoria y otra de peliculas mil gracias a quien me responda

Comment: Podrías poner la definición de las tablas? Esto ayudará a que te den una respuesta mas exacta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que haces, es contar en la columna nombre el número e registros que coincida que su nombre sea 'Terror', pero no nombras una columna de resultado, por lo que simplemente te aparece el resultado, puedes hacerlo con el renombramiento de la salida con "AS"

```
SELECT count(nombre) as PeliculasDeTerror FROM Categoria where nombre = 'Terror'
```

De esa forma te aparecerá una nueva columna denominada PeliculasDeTerror con el número de registros cuyo nombre sea 'Terror'

Comment: excelente mil gracias todo funcionando